# Solr 7.5 nodeAdded event behaviour

Tags: search, solr, replication, autoscaling

In Solr 7.5 there is nodeAdded event. However when I try to use it (running solr in local mode), it's behavior is quite strange. Let's assume I have 2 nodes and each node has one shard with 2 replicas. I have the following trigger defined:

```
{
  "set-trigger": {
    "name": "node_added_trigger_aa",
    "event": "nodeAdded",
    "waitFor": "1m",
    "preferredOperation": "ADDREPLICA",
    "enabled": true
  }
}
```

When I add a new node (so there are 3 nodes) one becomes empty, one is not changed and one starts to create a massive number of replicas. I checked and I don't see any recurrent triggers (I only added one posted above).
[Solr admin UI screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0W84p.png)

Do you experience the same issue? If you managed to get proper behavior please share the idea.

It may be related to this question: [Solr AutoScaling - Add replicas on new nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50839060/solr-autoscaling-add-replicas-on-new-nodes)

Comment: What is your exact question?

Comment: The question is do you experience the same issue. If not, how do you achieve proper behavior(I updated the question).

Comment: Not sure what you mean - in your screenshot there seems to be replicas on all three nodes? shard2 is replicated to `7574,8981`, while shard1 is replicated to `7574,8981(x3),8982(x3)? What did the layout look like (in the UI screenshot) before you added the new node? What was the parameters given when creating the collection?